# Uploading files to Django + Nginx doesn't save it in the media volume in Docker

Tags: django, docker, nginx

Basically whenever I try to upload a file using my website, the file doesn't get saved on the media volume.

I don't think its a code issue as it works perfectly fine without the container even when paired with nginx.

I followed this [tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/) to setup my docker containers.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /home/azureuser/ecommerce3

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# fixing alpine related pip errors
RUN apk update && apk add gcc libc-dev make git libffi-dev openssl-dev python3-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
RUN apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' ./entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh


# copy project
COPY . .

# running entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: sh -c "cd DVM-Recruitment-Task/ && gunicorn DVM_task3.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/azureuser/ecommerce3/staticfiles:Z
      - media_volume:/home/azureuser/ecommerce3/mediafiles:Z
      - log_volume:/home/azureuser/ecommerce3/logs
    expose:
      - 8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:13.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=---
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=---
      - POSTGRES_DB=---
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/DVM_task3:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - static_volume:/home/azureuser/ecommerce3/staticfiles/:Z
      - media_volume:/home/azureuser/ecommerce3/mediafiles/:Z
      - log_volume:/home/azureuser/ecommerce3/logs
      - (ssl certificate stuff here)
   volumes:
      postgres_data:
      media_volume:
      static_volume:
      log_volume:
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi
python DVM-Recruitment-Task/manage.py makemigrations ecommerce
python DVM-Recruitment-Task/manage.py migrate --noinput
python DVM-Recruitment-Task/manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear
exec "$@"
```

Also my nginx file already has this inside a server block

```
location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/azureuser/ecommerce3/mediafiles/;
    }
```

settings.py has this:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'mediafiles'
```

urls.py already has this line in it

```
urlpatterns[...] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also my project structure looks something like this:

```
.
├── DVM-Recruitment-Task
│  ├── DVM_task3
│  ├── README.md
│  ├── ecommerce
│  ├── manage.py
│  ├── static
│  └── templates
├── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── entrypoint.sh
├── nginx
│  └── DVM_task3
└── requirements.txt
```

everything inside a directory named 'ecommerce3'.

The mediafiles, staticfiles and logs volume are supposed to be created inside the same directory (ecommerce3).

On running --collectstatic the staticfiles load correctly, the logs work as well but the media files just won't save to the mediafiles folder.

if I go into the web container's shell and manually create a file inside the mediafiles directory, I am able to view in the /media url so I assume nginx is pointing in the right direction. However when it comes to saving the files, the files never get saved on this volume.

I am very new to django and docker so any help or nudge in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the **mediafiles** folder in your dockerfile

```
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/mediafiles
```

where **$APP_HOME** is where your app is located: **/home/azureuser/ecommerce3**